# How can I hide a GroupHeader in a report?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I have a GroupHeader in my report, and I have this code, but does not work:

```
Private Sub GroupHeader2_BeforePrint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs) Handles GroupHeader2.BeforePrint
    If lblDescription.Text = "" Then
        GroupHeader2.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I also put in the properties of the label `CanShrink = true`

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: I mean that is not hiding the GroupHeader, the GroupHeader is still appears.

Comment: In the debugger, is it getting to that code?

Comment: Yes in the debugger passes through the code